Power series solution using Leibniz-Maclaurin method of the Airy differential equation
I'm trying to get a power series solution to the differential equation $ y'' - xy = 0, y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 2 $, using two different methods, expanding about $ x = 0 $.
The first method is the 'normal' way of doing power series solutions, where we substitute $ y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n $, differentiate twice, sub into the differential equation, re-index, take out the first terms, combine and set everything inside the sum to zero. This gives a recurrence relation between the terms $ a_n $:
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n(n - 1)} a_{n-3}, \ \ \ \text{also} \ a_2 = 0 $$
which I believe is correct as it matches results elsewhere.
However, I then attempted to use the "Leibniz-Maclaurin" method. This is a method I had not heard of but found a video tutorial explaining it here, and many worked examples are shown here. I did the following:

Write the differential equation in Leibniz notation: $ y^{(2)} - xy = 0 $
Differentiate both sides with respect to $ x $, $ n $ times, using the Leibniz rule for repeated differentiation of a product:

$$ y^{(n+2)} - \left ( 1 \cdot x \cdot y^{(n)} + n \cdot 1 \cdot y^{(n-1)} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \cdot 0 \cdot y^{(n-2)} + ... \right ) = 0 $$
$$ y^{(n+2)} - x y^{(n)} - n y^{(n-1)} = 0 $$

To expand about $x=0$, set $x=0$:

$$ y^{(n+2)} - n y^{(n-1)} = 0 $$

Convert derivatives to sequence terms:

$$ a_{n+2} - n a_{n-1} = 0 $$

Therefore $ a_{n+2} = n a_{n-1} $, and re-indexing gives $ a_{n} = (n - 2) a_{n-3} $.

Clearly this is different to the first answer. Can anyone tell me what's gone wrong and how to do it correctly using this method?

The problem is in converting derivatives to coefficients.  Note that
$$ \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} x^n = n! $$
so $$ y^{(n+2)}(0) - n y^{n-1}(0) = 0$$
means $$ (n+2)! a_{n+2} - n (n-1)! a_{n-1} = 0 $$
and thus $$ (n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2} = a_{n-1} $$
which is equivalent to $a_n = \frac{1}{n(n-1)} a_{n-3}$.

Gotcha, thanks!!
